# Right Approach: Mapping ViewModel and DataModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, model, mapping

As far as I know, in MVVM, DataModel and ViewModel are two seperate concerns.

DataModel are more closer to DAL and are often hidden from views. This is not appropriate for rendering in views. View may needs different  Model. That is why we have ViewModel.

ViewModel is generalized/specialized version of datamodel. In most cases we can create viewmodel object using constructor passed with datamodel object.

```
ViewModel viewmodel=ViewModel(datamodel);
```

Can we do the same with creating DataModel  using constructor passed with ViewModel. Like

```
DataModel datamodel =DataModel (viewmodel);
```

What is good practice to map the view model to data model without any duplication of code?

Consider that I am doing mapping manually. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use AutoMapper ( google it for more details ). which enables more maintainability.